# Copying wordpress data model for post types and categories for custom developed site?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm building a user submission website and am trying to figure out a data model for categorizing content. I kind of want to copy how the wp_posts table seperates contents types using a "post types" column, but have heard that the data model isn't great due to it being built so long ago.

Basically I want to have 3 different types of categorizations

1. content_types (post_types) eg: Blog, Movies, Photos, Forums.
2. categories that can belong to all content types except forums: action, comedy and drama.
3. categories that can only belong to forums

Here's my current post table:

```
CREATE  `posts` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` text ,
  `date_added` date,
  `post_author` varchar(255),
  `post_title` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

***note*** all Images on the site will have their own table, unlike wordpress.

Would there be anything wrong with just adding a post_type(varchar) column to posts and just inserting the name of the post type every time someone makes a post? or should I make a post_types table. I don't really want to make a separate table for each post_type because the content will only have slight variances.

And to separate the Forum categories from the other categories should I create two separate tables or just one that would have an is_forum_cat column like so:

```
CREATE  `categories` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(255),
  `is_forum_cat` enum('0', '1'),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I'm new to data architecture, so any best practice advice, or if you can think of anything else I'd need to know , I'd welcome the advice.